# Query about Excel formula - Function IF(...)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to use the function IF() from Excel in a formula for some Cell, as shown below -

```
=IF(I2="SELL","(C2-F2)*D2","0")
```

Which means I want to see if Cell I2 has text- SELL in it (IF condition true), then I want the cell to have formula as (C2-F2)*D2, else if condition is false, it prints 0.

But trouble is that when condition is true, instead of putting the formula for the text it is putting the string (C2-F2)*D2 as it is in that Cell. What I want is that when condition is true, it should interpret (C2-F2)*D3 as formula in that cell. I tried many things , like -

```
=IF(I2="SELL","=((C2-F2)*D2)","0")
```

or

```
=IF(I2="SELL","=("(C2-F2)*D2)"","0")
```

but without any success.

Comment: Putting "" around "(C2-F2)*D2" changed it from a formula into a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

=IF(I2="SELL",(C2-F2)*D2,0) will put the required calculated values in the cell. The formula is the complete one with the IF

As said by others = "..." just gives the string between the "" and Excel will not try to evaluate it.

Comment: In excel quotation marks return the text between them rather than the results of the equation. This can be useful if you want to return a "Yes" from an IF statement, or as you have done use a "Sell" in the logical statement.

Answer (score 0):

"" will just paste a string.

Just use =IF(I2="SELL";(C2-F2)*D2;0)

Comment: May be typo , but it should not have semicolons, but commas as separators.

Comment: Sorry, that's just that I use the Spanish version of MS Office